# Why is Undyne giving me a letter after finishing the Neutral Route and reloading my save?

Tags: undertale

I defeated Asgore and Flowey then went back to the save point before the fights. I was travelling back to Snowdin just for fun, when I was told to bring the letter from Undyne to Alphys. I am doing a neutral route though.

Did the game glitch because I played it as if it was a pacafist route? Was this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds normal, assuming you have no EXP or LV.

Reloading before the final battle counts as having beaten the game. If you have no kills and have befriended everyone at this point, you fulfil all the criteria for a True Pacifist run.